# Nested Lock with the same name

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, mutex

if I have two locks nested
say (I am concerning java here）

```
synchronized (clientInfMutex) {
...
    synchronized (clientInfMutex) {
        //Will this part executable?


  }


}
```

Will the inner part executable? the concern is that when the outer lock is getting the lock, the inner lock might not be able to lock the lock again. If the inner part is not executable, is there a mechanism, such that if I hold the lock in the outer lock already, I will be able to access the inner lock without a problem? Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been faster to just test run your code?

Comment: What is the point of the inner synchronized block? You already hold the lock when you reach it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.
Because the thread will already have the lock.
In Java native locks are **reentrant**

Everytime the JVM hits a synchronized block, it checks if it has that lock, if no, then it waits for that lock, or else it increments an internal counter for that lock, and executes the enclosed block

Note that this is assuming that `clientInfMutex` points to same object in both statements. If, for e.g., you did a `clientInfMutex  = new Object()` between the two synchronized blocks, then your thread will wait for the lock of the new object.

Answer (score 2):

This will work just fine. If the thread already obtained a lock via `synchronized` block, it can re-obtain it multiple times. This feature is called [reentrant synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

Note that this also works if `this` is used implicitly as synchronizer:

```
public synchronized void foo() {
    bar();  //will NEVER block
}

public synchronized void bar() {
}
```

BTW the two code blocks in your sample are synchronizing on the same *object*, not on the same *name* as you call it.

Answer (score 0):

Every instance of Object in Java holds a single lock reference. That mean that the double lock you are using is actually lock the object only once. That also means that while you are in a block locked by an Object, locking again has no effect.